# How to use UserViewSet in djoser 2.0.3?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-views, djoser

I am new to Djoser and I am struggling to use the functions `UserView, UserViewCreate, UserViewDelete` to update,create and delete users.

The code I am using currently in `url_patterns` is:

```
from django.conf.urls import re_path
from djoser import views as djoser_views

urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^user/view/$', djoser_views.UserView.as_view(), name='user-view'),
    re_path(r'^user/delete/$', djoser_views.UserDeleteView.as_view(), name='user-delete'),
    re_path(r'^user/create/$', djoser_views.UserCreateView.as_view(), name='user-create'),

]
```

When I use UserView, I am getting the error as :

```
AttributeError: module 'djoser.views' has no attribute 'UserView'
```

I read the djoser documentation and saw that:

```
UserCreateView, UserDeleteView, UserView, PasswordResetView,SetPasswordView, PasswordResetConfirmView, SetUsernameView, ActivationView, and
ResendActivationView
```

These functions have all been removed and replaced by appropriate sub-views within UserViewSet.

I searched but couldn't find any way to use `UserViewSet`. Is there any way to use `UserViewSet` in djoser 2.0.3?

Answer (score 0):

you could try

```
urlpatterns = [
    re_path(r'^user/view/$', djoser_views.UserViewSet.retrieve.as_view(), name='user-view'),
    re_path(r'^user/delete/$', djoser_views.UserViewSet.destroy.as_view(), name='user-delete'),
    re_path(r'^user/create/$', djoser_views.UserViewSet.create.as_view(), name='user-create'),

]
```

but I would recommend following there documentation and use the lib as documented.